# Revalidate Tagged Page in NextJs 13 Using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Currently in NextJS 13 to revalidate tagged pages we can tag pages using `fetch`, but what If I need to use `axios` instead of `fetch`? Is there any way to to set tags.

Currently using fetch:
`await fetch('https://...', { next: { tags: ['collection'] } })`.

Comment: Did you figure out any methods for using axios?

Answer (score 0):

in my knowledge, We should't use Axios or any fetching 3rd party because we can't access request, revalidating , pre-fetch or other features wth  third-party fetching.
if we use revalidateTag() that trigger update cache and any fetching libraries that do not use fetch directly will not affect caching of a route, and will be static or dynamic depending on this route segment.